# Using var as value in attribute to select element

Tags: jquery, variables

Hi i have little problem with find solution for this code:

```
var attrVal = $('.class').attr('data-value'),
    select = $('.class2[data-value-select=$(attrVal)]').find('[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
```

How can i select element with data-value-select=(this attrVal) ?

Comment: try `'.class2[data-value-select=$(' + attrVal + ')]'`, if it does not help, then please include your html code

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution, was a little bit other:
`'.class2[data-value-select="' + attrVal + '"]'`

You are the best i forgot functionality of  '+'